# NextJS shallow routing will recreate _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to sync url with filters that user applied in my nextjs application.

I tried this code:

```js
router.replace(
  {
    search: stringify({ ...queryFromUrl, ...newQuery }, mergedStringifyOptions) || '?',
  },
  undefined,
  { shallow: true },
);
```

but this will recreate _app.js

If I remove `shallow: true` this will call `getStaticProps` again.

The problem I think is because filters does not exists in url at first. But How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "recreate _app.js"? Do you mean re-render?

Comment: @juliomalves somehow. I mean if I add console.log inside useEffect without any dependency, It log in console after I call code above.

Comment: That's expected, `_app` will re-render when calling `router.push`/`router.replace` but state is still maintained. [`shallow: true`](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) only means data fetching methods (like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`) do not run again.

Comment: @juliomalves No, empty `useEffect` in `_app.jsx` only called once when application loaded.